# How to show attribute dropdown in add to cart form in Commerce 2.x

Tags: commerce

The attribute dropdown list doesn't show, instead I get an autocomplete field labelled "Product Variation" and it contains the full title of the variation. When I enter text, a list of variations appear but when selecting a different variation the product doesn't refresh.

I would like it to show the label of the attribute with a dropdown list of the values. I'd like it to say "colour : "Value"". I have two attributes one showing a weight capacity the other a colour. They are both appended to the variation title but I need to select combinations of the two. I've trawled the internet and it seams the dropdown list should work out of the box.

I have a matching Product type and variation type. On the manage display of the product type the variation field format is "Add to Cart". On the variation type the attribute field is enabled but it doesn't show up.

Where am I going wrong please?

[image: Add to Cart Form Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have somehow disabled the proper widget. Go to the "Order item types" page and click "Manage form display" for your order item type, the widget for the "Purchased entity" field should be "Product variation attributes".

I would love to find out how your system ended up in this state. Was this a fresh install? Did you create a custom order item type? Let us know in the [Commerce issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/commerce).

Comment: Bojan, Thanks for the reply, your solution worked great, the problem is now solved! It was a fresh install using the "Default order item type". No new "order item types" were created, that's how it was automatically configured. I will gladly add an issue to the queue. Many thanks!

Comment: Is there any link to additional information on this, the issue added to the queue, etc.?  I am having the same problem, but for some reason the "fix" is not changing things - it seems strange that it isn't - I cannot figure out how to get the `class="form-autocomplete form-text required ui-autocomplete-input"` to change in the way described.

Comment: It's easy to answer how you end up with this. When you start, there is a single order item type, Default. And it defaults to Autocomplete rather than the Product variation attributes. So, when you duplicate it, it inherits the same. And as the previous comment says, it doesn't even fix the problem...

Comment: "And it defaults to Autocomplete rather than the Product variation attributes." - if it did on all installs (or even many), it would have been fixed a long time ago :)

Please open a bug report. I assume it's somehow related to the order in which you enabled Commerce modules.